# Implementing progress bar for a blazor hosted

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How do I implement progress bar for long running sever function on blazor hosted using signalR

I need to show the real time update of server function to the user. There are many tutorials on other framework but for blazor it's none. And i am new to signalR

Answer (score 0):

I don´t use server side Blazor but in my research for WebAssembly is somehow stumbled upon this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D) how to show a process bar for long running functions via SignalR.

In the tutorial ASP.NET MVC is used, but I think you can transform it to Blazor Server Side or at least get a starting point for implementing it.

Denis Lazendić who wrote the tutorial used some jQuery and Bootstrap code.

Maybe this helps you.

Comment: I've gone through this tutorial first. in this tutorial all available users geting the response from server. what i want is to get the response for the client who initialized long running task. Also i am referring this project to blazor web assembly, not server side blazor. thanks

Comment: Also I found this [tutorial](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/communicate-status-background-job-signalr/) but I couldn't convert javascript part to c#

Comment: Have you tried [calling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1) the JavaScript function from your C# code?